# How to prove some probability properties?

Tags: probability

I would like to prove the following:

1: If $B \supseteq A$ , then $\mathbb{P}(B) = \mathbb{P}(A) + \mathbb{P}(A^c \cap  B) \geqslant \mathbb{P}(A)$

2.$\mathbb{P}(B \cap A^c) = \mathbb{P}(B) - \mathbb{P}(A \cap B) $

For $1.$ I would say that $\mathbb{P}(A^c \cap B)$ is just $\mathbb{P}$ $(B\setminus A )$ and adding  $\mathbb{P}(A)$ gives $\mathbb{P}(B)$ because $A$ is a subset of $B$.

For 2 I just lost...

Comment: I'm also a bit lost on $2$. This statement starts with an `if`, but there's no corresponding `then`.

Comment: I'm sorry. I edited it.

Comment: And now we also lost `if`. This does not make things better, I am afraid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove 2, notice that $P(A\cap B)+P(A^c\cap B)=P((A\cup A^c)\cap B)=P(B)$

For 1, notice that $A=A\cap B$ so $P(A)+P(A^c\cap B)=P(A\cap B)+P(A^c\cap B)=P((A\cup A^c)\cap B)=P(B)$

Comment: Thank you. That means I just have to rearrange them? May I ask you to give me also a Hint on 1.

Comment: Edited to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

hint:

$$P(B)=P(A^c\cap B)+P(A\cap B)$$ This because the sets on RHS are disjoint and have $B$ as union.